# Why don't work notify-send from terminal?

Tags: notify-osd, notify-send

Ubuntu 16.04, notify 0.7.6

I tried `notify-send "something"`, and this doesn't work.
But `notify-send -u critical "test"` worked.
Why this happened?
I install notify-daemon, but this doesn't help me?
What can i do?
I would be grateful for help

Comment: Ubuntu version, flavour and `notify-send` version?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, notify 0.7.6

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the info in the question. Comments is not a good or safe place to provide important info.

Comment: in ubuntu 17.10 with libnotify-bin 0.7.7-2 it works.

Comment: this is no reason))

Comment: notify-send 0.7.6 here and it works for me too